# XSL adding attribute to parent based on child

Tags: xml, xslt

I started project in php, using XML, and now I need to apply transformation, so I've discovered XSL for the first time...

I've faced the problem: how to create XSL to do following transformation:
- node that starts with "attrib-" to transform to attribute of the parent node

## Example:

```
<a1>
  <b1>
    <attrib-c1>12</attrib-c1>
    <c2>23</c2>
  </b1>
</a1>
```

should become:

```
<a1>
  <b1 c1="12">
    <c2>23</c2>
  </b1>
</a1>
```

I've started solution like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would need some help to solve this task. Thanks in advance...

Comment: So all you've done is copied an identity transform.  Have you tried to solve the problem?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is almost the same solution as that of DevNull, but in case there is a conflict between an existing attribute and a new one defined by a child-element, the latter replaces the former**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="attr" select="*[starts-with(name(), 'attrib-')]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="attr" match="*[starts-with(name(), 'attrib-')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{substring-after(name(), 'attrib-')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'attrib-')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<a1>
  <b1 existing="attr" x="Y">
    <attrib-new>12</attrib-new>
    <c2>23</c2>
    <attrib-new2>ABCD</attrib-new2>
    <attrib-x>Z</attrib-x>
  </b1>
</a1>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a1>
   <b1 existing="attr" x="Z" new="12" new2="ABCD">
      <c2>23</c2>
   </b1>
</a1>
```

Answer (score 3):

**XML Input** (Modified to slightly increase complexity.)

```
<a1>
  <b1 existing="attr">
    <attrib-c1>12</attrib-c1>
    <c2>23</c2>
    <attrib-dh>DevNull</attrib-dh>
  </b1>
</a1>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(),'attrib')]" mode="attr"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'attrib')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="{substring-after(name(),'-')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<a1>
   <b1 c1="12" dh="DevNull" existing="attr">
      <c2>23</c2>
   </b1>
</a1>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. Also, `<xsl:element name="{name()}">` can be replaced with `<xsl:copy>`, right? You could also simplify `<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'attrib')]" mode="attr">` to `<xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">` if desired, since only elements starting with 'attrib-' will be processed in that mode anyway.

Comment: @LarsH - Thanks, those are great suggestions. Not sure why I didn't use `xsl:copy`; that's what I get for rushing.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, yeah, I had a nagging feeling I had forgotten it. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match elements with children like attrib- and copy/pass -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*[starts-with(name(.),'attrib')]]">
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(.),'attrib')]"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(starts-with(name(.),'attrib'))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match elements like attrib- and output them as attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(.),'attrib')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{substring-after(name(.),'attrib-')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good, but be careful about the `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(starts-with(name(.),'attrib'))]"/>`. This fails to copy children other than elements (e.g. text nodes, comments, etc.).